# PHP combinations using all words each time

Tags: php, arrays, string, combinations

This is my first question at this site, so I hope that I will be specific enough with this.

I need to transform a text string into several array with all different combinations of the 'words' and 'word phrases' in the text string.

So string would be like:
"Football match France 2013"

From this I want the following array:

```
array(
0 => array(
    'Football',
    'match',
    'France',
    '2013'
),
1 => array(
    'Football',
    'match',
    'France 2013'
),
2 => array(
    'Football',
    'match France',
    '2013'
),
3 => array(
    'Football',
    'match France 2013'
),
4 => array(
    'Football match',
    'France',
    '2013'
),
5 => array(
    'Football match',
    'France 2013',
),
6 => array(
    'Football match France',
    '2013'
),
7 => array(
    'Football match France 2013',
),
```

)

So the restriction that a each result string string may consist of 1 to n consecutive words and that in total each sub array should contain each word one time.

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: Is this your homework, or do you practically need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code that works.

```
<?php 

$str = 'Football match France 2013'; // Initialize sentence
$words = explode(" ",$str); // Break sentence into words
$p = array(array(array_shift($words))); // Load first word into permutation that has nothing to connect to

foreach($words as $word) { // for each remaining word
    $a = $p; // copy existing permutation for not-connected set
    $b = $p;  // copy existing permutation for connected set
    $s = count($p); // cache number of items in permutation
    $p = array(); // reset permutation (attempt to force garbage collection before adding words)
    for($i=0;$i<$s;$i++) { // loop through each item
       $a[$i][] = $word; // add word (not-connected)
       $b[$i][count($b[$i])-1] .= " ".$word; // add word (connected)
    }
    $p = array_merge($a,$b); // create permutation result by joining connected and not-connected sets
}

// Dump the array
print_r($p);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you !
I am still amazed how quick response is here.

Comment: I would die happy if I understood how you managed to conceive that.

Comment: nl-x this is a permutation problem where each word can be connected to the previous word, or not connected to the previous word. The singularity case (first word) needs to be pre-loaded into the buffer since it won't have anything to connect to. Then as each word is added it doubles the size of the array because there are only two possible states (connected,not connected). All of the existing members with the new word connected, and all of the existing members with the new word not connected.

Comment: nl-x I have added some comments to make the algorithm easier to understand.

Comment: @RalphRitoch are you trying to kill nl-x?